# Visual Studio: Open brace on newline only for multi-line wrapped statements?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Generally, I prefer to put opening braces on the same line so less vertical space is taken up by braces. I can configure Visual Studio's "Code Style - Formatting" settings for this.

However, this setting is problematic for long statements that have been manually split into multiple lines:

```
public void LongExampleFunction(Dictionary<string, int> map, bool doSomething, 
    bool anotherThing, int iterations, Action<int, string> callback) {
    if (doSomething && !anotherThing) {
        int count = 0;
        //...
```

With this formatting, because the additional lines have the same indentation as the code inside the method, it's not immediately obvious where the method declaration ends and the inside of the method begins.

Is there a way to configure VS to format the code like this?

```
// New line when the statement is long and split into multiple lines
public void LongExampleFunction(Dictionary<string, int> map, bool doSomething, 
    bool anotherThing, int iterations, Action<int, string> callback) 
{
    // Same line when the statement is short
    if (doSomething && !anotherThing) {
        int count = 0;
        //...
```

Comment: I don't think VS has separate bracing options for single- and multi-line declarations, but I can present an alternative: instead if starting the next line at one indentation, start it directly under the first parameter. That way it will be clearer which of the lines are continuing the parameter list and which are beginning the code (that is how my IDE starts a new line when breaking up long parameter lists).

Comment: You can try Tools=>Options=>Text Editor=>C#=>Code Style=>Formatting=>New Lines, how to uncheck "Place open brace on new line for methods and local functions"

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT This does not answer my question. Please read the question more carefully.